# How to apply multple condtions on a single key in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backend

I am trying to apply two conditions to a single key.
I have to get documents that have "status(a key) as 'SCHEDULED' and isDone as false" OR
they have any status from an array like `['MISSED','CANCELLED']`. This array is coming correctly.
So far I have tried: -

```
con['$or'] = [
        { "$and" : [ {status : 'SCHEDULED'} , {isDone: false} ] },
        { status : { "$in" : userData.statusFilter } }
]
```

I am sending this con object as the first parameter in find query.

```
Category.find(con, {}, skipCondtion, function(err,res){
     if(err) {
       res.send(err)
     } else {
       console.log(res)
     }
})
```

I am only getting documents that meet the first in $or i.e., where status is 'SCHEDULED' and isDone is false.

(I am using skipCondtion for pagination purpose.)

Comment: Your query should work. Are you sure you're passing a proper array in `userData.statusFilter`?

Comment: Yes. I checked it so many times. That's why I got confused. I thought maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: Make sure you have documents with other status also present in the collection.

Comment: I have them. When I try to get data without any filter, I get documents with other status also.